# SUMIFS nested in IF Statement - excluding blanks

Tags: excel, if-statement, excel-2010, sumifs

I am trying to get the following:

If cell b3 equals P1 then sum column R as long as column D equals cell d6 and column E is not blank, if cell b3 does not equal P1 then .....

Here is the formula:

```
=IF($B$3="P1",SUMIFS('Budget Money'!R:R,'Budget Money'!D:D,D6,'Budget Money'!E:E,"<>"),
 IF($B$3="P2",SUMIFS(‘Budget Money’!R:R,'Budget Money'!D:D,D6,'Budget Money'!F:F,"<>"),
 IF($B$3="P3",SUMIFS(‘Budget Money’!R:R,'Budget Money'!D:D,D6,'Budget Money'!G:G,"<>"),
 IF($B$3="P4",SUMIFS(‘Budget Money’!R:R,'Budget Money'!D:D,D6,'Budget Money'!H:H,"<>"),
 IF($B$3="P5",SUMIFS(‘Budget Money’!R:R,'Budget Money'!D:D,D6,'Budget Money'!I:I,"<>"),
 IF($B$3="P6",SUMIFS(‘Budget Money’!R:R,'Budget Money'!D:D,D6,'Budget Money'!J:J,"<>"),
 IF($B$3="P7",SUMIFS(‘Budget Money’!R:R,'Budget Money'!D:D,D6,'Budget Money'!K:K,"<>"),
 IF($B$3="P8",SUMIFS(‘Budget Money’!R:R,'Budget Money'!D:D,D6,'Budget Money'!L:L,"<>"),
 IF($B$3="P9",SUMIFS(‘Budget Money’!R:R,'Budget Money'!D:D,D6,'Budget Money'!M:M,"<>"),
 IF($B$3="P10",SUMIFS(‘Budget Money’!R:R,'Budget Money'!D:D,D6,'Budget Money'!N:N,"<>"),
 IF($B$3="P11",SUMIFS(‘Budget Money’!R:R,'Budget Money'!D:D,D6,'Budget Money'!O:O,"<>"),
 IF($B$3="P12",SUMIFS(‘Budget Money’!R:R,'Budget Money'!D:D,D6,'Budget Money'!P:P,"<>")))))))))))))
```

For the last part of the sumifs statements I have tried "<>", "<>"&"", "<>"&"" and I get the error: The formula contains unrecognized text

Comment: In some places, you have 'back-ticks' instead of ticks in `‘Budget Money’`; should be `'Budget Money'`. Other than that, look below for a simplification of your formula.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this is one statement with any `IF` conditionals.

Because your column offset is basically defined by cell `$B$3`, then use that with the `OFFSET` formula to calculate where the column comes from:

```
=SUMIFS('Budget Money'!R:R,'Budget Money'!D:D,D7,OFFSET('Budget Money'!D:D,0,RIGHT(B1,LEN(B1)-1)),"<>")
```

Comment: I was just about to suggest `=SUMIFS('Budget Money'!R:R, 'Budget Money'!D:D, D6, INDEX('Budget Money'!E:P, 0, INT(MID(B3, 2, 2))),"<>")`.

Comment: @PeterT, your answer worked and is much cleaner, thanks!